Hibernate reactive and SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator
I've got two Hibernate entities EntityA and EntityB (in Kotlin). These have a one to one mapping defined:
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator",
    strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = [Parameter(name = "property", value = "bookLineItem")]
)
@Column(
    name = ENTITY_B_ID,
    unique = true,
    nullable = false
)
var entityBId: Int? = null

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
@JsonBackReference
var entityA: EntityA? = null

This works ok for non-reactive Hibernate. The ID of EntityB will be set to the same ID of EntityA.
In https://hibernate.org/reactive/documentation/2.3/reference/html_single/#_identifier_generation it is mentioned

Custom identifier generators written to work with Hibernate ORM and
JDBC will not work in the reactive environment

And fair enough I am currently getting
Can not set java.lang.Integer field com.acme.repository.model.EntityB.entityBId to org.hibernate.action.internal.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier

I will have to use ReactiveIdentifierGenerator see https://javadoc.io/doc/org.hibernate.reactive/hibernate-reactive-core/latest/org/hibernate/reactive/id/ReactiveIdentifierGenerator.html
but I can't see any examples. I also can't find any specifics on the SharedPrimaryKeyGenerator
So how would I implement this that the ID of EntityB is set to the ID that was generated for EntityA?
Update:
I've now implemented a custom ID generator
    class ReactiveSharedPrimaryKeyGenerator: ReactiveIdentifierGenerator<Int> {
    override fun generate(p0: ReactiveConnectionSupplier?, entity: Any?): CompletionStage<Int> {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync {
            val primaryKey = getPrimaryKey(entity!!)
            primaryKey as Int ?: throw IllegalStateException("Primary Key value is null")
        }.toCompletableFuture()
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ID or the One2One parent by checking for the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn field to retrieve the parent
     * and then searches for the field annotated with @Id to retrieve the ID of the parent
     */
    fun getPrimaryKey(entity: Any?): Int? {
        entity?.let {
            var currentClass: Class<*> = it::class.java
            while (currentClass != null && currentClass != Any::class.java) {
                currentClass.declaredFields.forEach { field ->
                    val annotation = field.getAnnotation(PrimaryKeyJoinColumn::class.java)
                    annotation?.let { an ->
                        field.trySetAccessible()
                        val primaryKeyOwner = field.get(it)
                        primaryKeyOwner?.let { pk ->
                            val primaryKeyField = pk::class.java.getDeclaredFields().find { pkF ->
                                pkF.getAnnotation(javax.persistence.Id::class.java) != null
                            }
                            if (primaryKeyField != null) {
                                primaryKeyField.trySetAccessible()
                                val pkId = primaryKeyField.get(pk)
                                return pkId as Int?
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                currentClass = currentClass.superclass
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}

and annotated the ID of EntityB with
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "custom-generator",
        strategy = "com.acme.repository.ReactiveSharedPrimaryKeyGenerator",
        parameters = [Parameter(name = "property", value = "entityA")]
    )

The method is called and I can find the parent class and the ID field but when this method is called the ID is still null!
2nd Update
I've tried the @MapsId approach
@Id
var entityBId: Int? = null

@OneToOne
@MapsId
@JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_B_ID")
var entityA: EntityA? = null

But that fails with
Can not set java.lang.Integer field
 com.acme.repository.model.EntityB.entityBId 
 to org.hibernate.action.internal.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier


This could be a bug. I've created issue 1912 for it. If you want to provide a test case, it might speed up having a fix for it. Thanks.
